# Piwik vs. Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, matomo

I run both piwik and google analytics on my site. I have noticed that the google analytics data is totally wrong. It does not seem to register any hits while piwik does. What could be wrong?

Comment: Does analytics register 0 hits, or just fewer than piwik?

Comment: Most of the time 0 hits, however sometimes up to 10% of piwiks. Even my own hits without any blocking are not registered in google analytics.

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation is that some of your users block Google Analytics. This is common, for instance, if you use NoScript in Firefox.

Comment: Yea, that's one of the downsides to JS-based analytics versus image-tag/logfile-analysis/packet-analysis/server-side-scripting-based analytics. Though JS-based analytics can give you a lot more information.

Comment: piwik is also js-based. there shouldn't be a difference if it is javascript blocking

Comment: @txwikinger: AFAIK, Piwik also has non-JavaScript tracking. Though whether it's enabled by default or not, I don't know. Check your config file. Though given your other comment, it seems like Google Analytics probably isn't set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the google analytics debugger for chrome?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

That shows in the developer tools console when things are firing.

Also is the site / GA account new, or are you taking over from a previous webmaster? If you are taking it over then have you checked that there isn't some crazy filter in place in GA?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways may be that your Google Analytics code is placed wrong (not sitewide block) or it conflicts with some other JS codes (e.g. old GA code).